# Problem Downgrading Node Version in Angular Project with NVM

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to downgrade the Node.js version in my Angular project using NVM (Node Version Manager). I'm specifically aiming to shift to Node.js version 16.20.2. However, upon executing nvm use 16, an error message claims that Node v16.20.2 is not installed, even though I've verified its installation.

I've also experimented with the latest Node.js version, which unfortunately isn't compatible with my Angular CLI, resulting in the same error message.

Surprisingly, when attempting to switch to version 20, I'm told that "node v20.9.0 is not installed," despite the fact that node -v indicates my current version is v20.9.0.

I'd highly appreciate any guidance or insights on how to manage this version switch effectively. Your help is much appreciated!